# Netsuite: Your connection has timed out

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, soap, netsuite

I've developed a C# script in Visual Studio to connect to NetSuite webservices. Last week my script worked fine, but today I logged with token authentication, and when I want to do some tests, an exception occurred:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Services.dll
>
> Additional information: Your connection has timed out.  Please log in
>   again.

I've search in every forum, other people have the same problem, but I still haven't found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the best way for authentication is to use Request Level Credentials like this:

```
// Create NetSuiteService instance
NetSuiteService _service = new NetSuiteService();

// Do not create CookieContainer as we don't want to keep session informatiom
// _service.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

// Create Passport and assign it to _service.passport
Passport passport = new Passport();
passport.account = "ACCT12345";
passport.email = "user@domain.com";
passport.password = "password";
_service.passport = passport;

// Create an example reference to Customer ID 100
RecordRef recref = new RecordRef();
recref.type = RecordType.customer;
recref.typeSpecified = true;
recref.internalId = "100";

// Fetch Customer record
ReadResponse response_get = _service.get(recref);
```

Answer Id: `34545`

Comment: Token authentication abruptly stopped working for my production Netsuite account on April 19, 2018. Switching to per-request authentication fixed the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. can you explain the solution in more detail please?